# How do I change the data type of a Julia array from "Any" to "Float64"?

Tags: arrays, julia

Is there a function in Julia that returns a copy of an array in a desired type, i.e., an equivalent of [numpys astype function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)? I have an "Any" type array, and want to convert it to a Float array. I tried:

```
new_array = Float64(array)
```

but I get the following error

```
LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching 
convert(::Type{Float64}, ::Array{Any,2})
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Float64(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert(::Type{Float64}, !Matched::Int8)
  convert(::Type{Float64}, !Matched::Int16)
  ...
  while loading In[140], in expression starting on line 1

  in call at essentials.jl:56
```

I can just write a function that goes through the array and returns a float value of each element, but I find it a little odd if there's no built-in method to do this.

Comment: There are several answers below that seem to be correct. You should select whichever you think is best as the answer.

Answer (score 24):

Use `convert`. Note the syntax I used for the first array; if you know what you want before the array is created, you can declare the type in front of the square brackets. `Any` just as easily could've been replaced with `Float64` and eliminated the need for the `convert` function.

```
julia> a = Any[1.2, 3, 7]
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 1.2
 3  
 7  

julia> convert(Array{Float64,1}, a)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.2
 3.0
 7.0
```

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the broadcast operator `.`:

```
a = Any[1.2, 3, 7]
Float64.(a)
```

Comment: Thank you sir,

I almost lost a hope to convert dataframe obtained via CSV.read to Int16 from default Int64. For some reason, "types" and "type" keyword arguments just ignored and you always get Int64

This worked for me
df = Int16.(CSV.read("file.csv"))

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

`new_array = Array{Float64}(array)`

Answer (score 2):

Daniel and Randy's answers are solid, I'll just add another way here I like because it can make more complicated iterative cases relatively succinct. That being said, it's not as efficient as the other answers, which are more specifically related to conversion / type declaration. But since the syntax can be pretty easily extended to other use case it's worth adding:

```
a = Array{Any,1}(rand(1000))
f = [float(a[i]) for i = 1:size(a,1)]
```

Comment: I used this approach when converting string entries read in from CSV directly to get the values  't4new = [parse(t4[i]) for i=1:length(t4)]`. this gives me the array of int values I needed as you expected your use is extensible.